# Icon that when clicked would launch to my website

Tags: android

I would think this would be one of the simpler and popular app questions on the net, but I have been unable to find any info…

I would like to create an icon that when clicked would launch to my website which has been modified for mobile devices. I would like to make this available on the android market.

Does anyone know how to do this or know where I can find a step by step guide?

Matt

Comment: What BicycleDude said. Those would be the key things I was going to suggest. `ImageButton`, `OnClickListener` and `Webview`. I'd also add the link to this http://developer.android.com/index.html and using the Dev Guide, Reference and Resources sections plus the Search box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using the WebView control? Then your UI can be a local HTML with an image button and you configure it with an onclick event that refresh the WebView control with your target website?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys!
Where would I insert the Webview? r.java file?

Comment: Not the R.java file, that is generated. WebView goes dynamically in your Activity or you can defined it in the XML layout.